# How to get the LatLngBounds of a Circle in Google maps given its center and radius?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, coordinates, geometry

How can I get the Northeast and Southwest coordinates of a Circle with a given center and radius? I can't find any solution anywhere. Currently, the Circle object doesn't have getLatLngBounds() nor getBounds() methods unlike before.

Comment: There is a solution using only simple math in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440092/geo-circle-to-rectangle-coordinates/48440582#48440582).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the `SphericalUtil.computeOffset` method from the 
[Google Maps Android API Utility Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/utility). To use it you need to the following dependency to your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

Then, you can calculate the northeast and southwest coordinates of your circle doing:

```
double radius = 104.52;
LatLng center = new LatLng(40.22861, -3.95567);

LatLng targetNorthEast = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, radius * Math.sqrt(2), 45);
LatLng targetSouthWest = SphericalUtil.computeOffset(center, radius * Math.sqrt(2), 225);
```

Comment: What do heading 45 and 225 mean?

Comment: 45 are the degrees towards north east (0 means north), and 225 are the degrees towards south west (180 degrees which is south plus 45 degrees)

Answer (score 4):

Essentially copying and pasting antonio's answer:

```
    public static LatLngBounds getLatLngBoundsFromCircle(Circle circle){
        if(circle != null){
            return new LatLngBounds.Builder()
                    .include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(circle.getCenter(), circle.getRadius() * Math.sqrt(2), 45))
                    .include(SphericalUtil.computeOffset(circle.getCenter(), circle.getRadius() * Math.sqrt(2), 225))
                    .build();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: hey can you tell me why you do multiply Math.sqrt(2). why not just use the radius as the distance without that ? i think  distanceFromCenterToCorner is what that is right .looks like its a way to get the corner distance from the center. cool.

Comment: You are right. The multiplication by sqrt(2) is for a padding. It is not mandatory, the radius is enough.