# How can I drag and drop a marker in a limited area?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, gps

How can I drag and drop a marker in a limited area? For instance, a circle has 20 meters radius. User can only drag and drop inside the circle. Here is the code I've tried.

```
map.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
        mymarker.setPosition(latLng);
        mGoogleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }
});

map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker arg0) {
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker arg0) {
        Log.d("System out", "onMarkerDragEnd...");
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(arg0.getPosition()));
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker arg0) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When drag starts you can move map to bounds in which you want to limit dragging. And disable map gestures to prevent map moving. If you have zoom or my location controls they can be disabled here as well. After drag ends you enable them back.

```
map.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(marker.getPosition(), 15));
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {}

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        map.getUiSettings().setAllGesturesEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

To get `LatLngBounds` by center and radius you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37304415/3252320).

Comment: Thank you so much !