# How to change the camera Zoom while changing the circle radius

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, maps

I am controlling  the circle radius around my current position with a seekbar

```
mycircle=   mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(myCurrentPostion).radius(200).fillColor(Color.argb(100,0,255,255)).strokeColor(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

on the onProgressChanged of the seekbar, i set the new radius

```
mycircle.setRadius(progress*1000);
```

when the circle increase or decrease i should see the bounds of the circle.
how can i do this?

i tried with the onCameramovelistener

```
  mMap.setOnCameraMoveListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraMoveListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onCameraMove() {
                              mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(getLatLngBoundsFromCircle(mycircle),30));
                            }
                        });
```

but when i set the seekbar, i should touch the screen to see the camera zoom change.

any help to see camera zoom change at the same time of setting the seekbar?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37303931/how-to-get-the-latlngbounds-of-a-circle-in-google-maps-given-its-center-and-radi/37304415#37304415

Comment: Just 'moveCamera' when you '.setRadius'.   The posted code moves the camera _only_ when the camera has moved which is not right.

Comment: Thank you Andy. problem solved.